# How to implement GetHashCode for NHibernate entity with identity column?

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate

I came to a conclusion that it is impossible to properly implement `GetHashCode()` for an NHibernate entity with an identity column. The only working solution I found is to return a constant. See below for explanation.

This, obviously, is terrible: all dictionary searches effectively become linear. Am I wrong? Is there a workaround I missed?

**Explanation**

Let's suppose we have an Order entity that refers to one or more Product entities like this:

```
class Product
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; } // auto; assigned by the database upon insertion
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; } // foreign key into the Orders table
}
```

"Id" is what is called an [IDENTITY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933196%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) column in SQL Server terms: an integer key that is automatically generated by the database when the record is inserted.

Now, what options do I have for implementing `Product.GetHashCode()`? I can base it on

- `Id` value
- `Name` value
- Identity of the product object (default behavior)

Each of these ideas does not work. If I base my hash code on Id, it will change when the object is inserted into a database. The following was experimentally shown to break, at least in the presence of NHibernate.SetForNet4:

```
/* add product to order */

var product = new Product { Name = "Sushi" }; // Id is zero
order.Products.Add(product); // GetHashCode() is calculated based on Id of zero
session.SaveOrUpdate(order); 

// product.Id is now changed to an automatically generated value from DB
// product.GetHashCode() value changes accordingly
// order.Products collection does not like it; it assumes GetHashCode() does not change

bool isAdded = order.Products.Contains(product); 

// isAdded is false; 
// the collection is looking up the product by its new hash code and not finding it
```

Basing `GetHashCode()` on the object identity (i.e. leaving `Product` with default implementation) does not work well either, it was covered on StackOverflow before. Basing `GetHashCode()` on `Name` is obviously not a good idea if `Name` is mutable.

So, what is left? The only thing that worked for me was

```
class Product
{
    ...
    override public GetHashCode() { return 42; }
}
```

Thanks for reading through this long quesiton.
**Do you have any ideas on how to make it better?**

PS. Please keep in mind that this is an NHibernate question, not collections question. The collection type and the order of operations are not arbitrary. They are tied to the way NHibernate works. For instance, I cannot simply make Order.Products to be something like IList. It will have important implications such as requiring an index/order column, etc.

Comment: Why are you mutating objects while they're currently inside of a dictionary?  *That's* the behavior that shouldn't be happening.  In this specific case, it likely means you should be populating the dictionary only after the objects have all generated their ID values.  Just don't use that data structure if they haven't yet had that populated.  Also, do you have multiple objects representing the same DB line?  If not, just don't override `GetHashCode` at all, and the reference comparison will be what you want.

Comment: I am not mutating the object - NHibernate does. What exactly is your suggestion? Saving the product first before saving the order may not be possible, especially if it is a new order. Think of a situation that Products table has OrderId field, which is a non-nullable foreign key into the Orders table. If you save the product first, what do you put in the OrderId?

Comment: Who mutates it is irrelevant.  It is getting mutated while in a dictionary.  You shouldn't be doing that.  *That's* why it's not working.  Without knowing what your project is actually doing, I can't really say much more.  I'd need details of the application to know how you could avoid using a dictionary.  It's likely better to just use some other data structure, one that's not hash based, such as a `List`, instead.

Comment: The application saves orders to the database :) That's why it uses NHibernate. Can't use list for NHibernate children. It requires an index column. See http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/#collections-ofvalues

Comment: When persisting the Product, the Order has to be persisted already. The Dictionary holding the Products of an Order gets out-of-date while you are persisting the Product. (In fact it can remain out-of-date til you need it updated. This end of the association is not "controlling" it.)

Comment: Hm... Are you saying that the order of operations should be 1. Create order, save. 2. Create new Product { Order = myOrder }; Save, and only then 3. Order.Products.Add(product)? Can you write a working sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would base the hashcode (and equality, obviously) on the Id, that's the right thing to do. Your problem stems from the fact that you modify Id while the object is in the Dictionary. Objects should be immutable in terms of hashcode and equality while they are inside a dictionary or hashset.

You have two options -

1. Don't populate dictionaries or hashsets before storing items in DB
2. Before saving an object to the DB, remove it from the dictionaries. Save it to the DB and then add it again to the dictionary.

**Update**

The problem can also be solved by using others mappings

1. You can use a bag mapping - it will be mapped to an IList and should work OK with you. No need to use HashSets or Dictionaries.
2. If the DB schema is under your control, you may wish to consider adding an index column and making the relation ordered. This will again be mapped to an IList but will have a List mapping.

There are differences in performance, depending on your mappings and scenarios (see http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/#performance-collections-mostefficientupdate)

Comment: You actually *can't* remove the item from the dictionary once the data the hash is based off of has changed.  That's what makes it so evil.  When you give it the object to remove it's looking in the wrong bucket, so it thinks it's not there.

Comment: I modified the question to make clear that we have a 1-to-many relationship between Orders and Products. If you have a 1-to-many relationship, you add children to the parent by putting them in a dictionary. Can you provide a sample for creating a new order with a new product without putting the product in a dictionary?

Comment: @Vadim: I agree with your and Servy's point that modifying hash code of an object in a dictionary is a bad idea. The trouble is, NHibernate makes be use dictionaries (or sets) to model unordered 1:n relationships. How do you get around that?

Comment: @IvanKrivyakov - I think you can also solve your issue by using other mappings, I've my answer.

Comment: Alright, this makes much more sense now. These are still workarounds, because I don't care about the order, and an Order can't contain the same product twice, so bag does not make perfect sense. But it will probably do the job.

Comment: @IvanKrivyakov, something is still bugging me with my answer. Could you please post your code of the Order class? Is this the only place where you'll have dictionaries or sets? Because if not, then my answer is no good.